# I stored Json to one variable and how i can show the json values to textview

Tags: java, android, json

```
    package com.kovan.thefishchain;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.kovan.thefishchain.model.Item;
import com.kovan.thefishchain.model.OrderInfo;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpEntity;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.methods.HttpGet;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Created by Rahul on 6/1/2016.
 */
public class OrderConformation extends Activity  implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button placeorder;
    private TextView cus_id,order_date,cus_name,cus_email,cust_name,cus_add,cus_mobile,fixedrate,quantity,price,subtotal,tax,discount,grandtotal,subtotallast,
            shippingcharge,total;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order_conformation_page);

        cus_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customerr_id);
        order_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.order_date);
        cus_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
        cus_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_email);
        cust_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_name1);
        cus_add = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_address);
        cus_mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customer_number);
        fixedrate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fixed_rate);
        quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qty);
        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
        subtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
        tax = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tax);
        discount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.discount);
        grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rowtotal);
        subtotallast = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotal_last);
        shippingcharge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shipping_charge);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grand_total);
        placeorder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_placeorder);


        try
        {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OrderConformation.this);
            String emailsts = prefs.getString("Orderinfo", "");
            String obj = gson.toJson(emailsts);//this will works
            Log.i("fine", obj);

            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(obj);//here not works,i tried to check in log
            String cust_id = object.optString("customer_id");
           // Log.i("mmmmmmm",cust_id);
            String order_dat = object.getString("ordered_at");
           // Log.i("nnnnnnnnn",order_dat);
            String name = object.getString("name");
            String mobnum = object.getString("phone");
            String addr = object.getString("street1");
            String rate = object.getString("pricePerUnit");
            String quan = object.getString("qty");
            String prize = object.getString("pricePerUnit");
            String subtot =object.getString("subTotal");
            String taxes = object.getString("taxAmount");
            String discounts = object.getString("discountAmount");
            String total = object.getString("rowTotal");

            Toast.makeText(OrderConformation.this,total.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            cus_id.setText(cust_id);
            order_date.setText(order_dat);
            cus_name.setText(name);
            cus_mobile.setText(mobnum);
            cus_add.setText(addr);
            fixedrate.setText(rate);
            quantity.setText(quan);
            price.setText(prize);
            subtotal.setText(subtot);
            tax.setText(taxes);
            discount.setText(discounts);
            grandtotal.setText(total);

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



        placeorder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                new Orderapi().execute();
                Intent intent = new Intent(OrderConformation.this, OrderConformationFinal.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(OrderConformation.this, "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OrderConformation.this);
        String emailsts = prefs.getString("Orderinfo", "");
        String obj = gson.toJson(emailsts);
        Log.i("fine", obj);

       /* OrderInfo odr = new OrderInfo(obj);
        Log.i("ord",odr.toString());
        Log.i("odrrr", gson.toJson(odr));
        String cust_id = odr.getCustomerId("customer_id");
        String order_id = odr.getOrderedAt("ordered_id");
        String name = odr.getPartner().getName("name");
        String mobnum = odr.getPartner().getMobile("phone");
        String addr = odr.getPartner(). getStreet1("street1");
        cus_id.setText(cust_id);
        order_date.setText(order_id);
        Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(cus_id));
        Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(order_date));
*/

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
    class Orderapi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //final String order_idd = getIntent().getStringExtra("orderId");
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            /*  HttpGet httGet = new HttpGet("http://52.21.243.46:8080/JStoreConnector/rest/api/store/odoo/order/orderId/placeOrder"
                    + order_idd);*/
            HttpGet httGet = new HttpGet("http://52.21.243.46:8080/JStore/rest/api/store/odoo/order/order/placeOrder");
            HttpResponse resp = null;
            try {
                resp = httpclient.execute(httGet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpEntity entityResponse = resp.getEntity();
            String value = null;
            try {
                value = EntityUtils.toString(entityResponse);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }
    }}
```

i used shared preference concept to store the previous page json..i checked the json that will correct...in orderConformation page try part will not work here..how to set the key values to textview...i used gson here..can anyone please solve my problem?

Comment: Can you try to make a [mcve] demonstrating the same problem? You may [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, you have Gson... So you should not be using Androids builtin JSONObject class.

Comment: k...please give some solution

Comment: You do know that Gson is used to both serialize and deserialize Java objects? So you've serialized some object into SharedPreferences, so you need to figure out how to deserialize it using Gson, and not manually parse it by JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

You have to use :

```
ObjectType object = gson.fromJson(obj);
```

instead of

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(obj);
```

Where obj is the string containing the json serialization

You may want to check this [example](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#primitives-examples)

Comment: Provide more information, what will not work for you ? This is the method that you should use to create an object from json

Comment: Replace ObjectType with the type of your object, in this case, String.

Comment: this shows String will not allowd to gson.fromJson(obj);

Answer (score 1):

for Set object in Preferance

PreferanceUtils.setObjectInPreferance(context, new Gson().toJson(OBJECT).toString());

Get Object From Preferance

Object obj = PreferanceUtils.getObjectFromPreferance(context);

public class PreferanceUtils {

```
private static final String PREFERENCE_NAME = "App Name";
private static final String OBJCETNAME = "Object Name";

/**
 * Insert string value in Shared Preferences
 *
 * @param context of application
 * @param value   to store in preferences
 * @param key     using which value is mapped
 * @return
 */
public static boolean putStringInPreferences(final Context context,
                                             final String value, final String key) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context
            .getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get Data from preferance
 *
 * @param context
 * @param defaultValue
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public static String getStringFromPreferences(final Context context,
                                              final String defaultValue, final String key) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context
            .getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String temp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
    return temp;
}

/**
 * 
 *
 * @param context
 * @param users
 */
public static void setObjectInPreferance(Context context, String users) {
    PreferanceUtils.putStringInPreferences(context, users,
            OBJCETNAME);
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @param context
 * @return
 *
 */
public static Object getObjectFromPreferance(Context context) {
    return new Gson().fromJson(PreferanceUtils.getStringFromPreferences(context, "",
            OBJCETNAME), Object.class);
}
```

}